# How to invoke the OS command (shell file) with argument in R

Tags: r, system, invoke

I like to invoke the OS command (running a shell file in linux) within R code and send argument together that I got in the R code. For example, MyRcode.R will do some calculation and get a vector output. Then, MyRcode.R will use for loop to run a shell file and send each element in the vector. Here is a simple example of code.

[MyRcode.R]

```
############################################
### Some calculation to get myVector  ######
                   .
                   .
############################################

print(myVector)  # [1]  3  5   7
for (argument in myVector) {
    system("./Shell_RunCalculations.sh argument")
}
```

[Shell_RunCalculations.sh]

```
#!/bin/bash

module load R/3.5.1-gcc5.2.0

echo "argument: " $1 

Rscript --vanilla RunCalculation.R $1
```

[RunCalculation.R]

```
### This is very complex calculation which should run in Supercomputer.
```

First, in the shell file, I expected to print

```
argument: 3
argument: 5
argument: 7
```

However, it printed out

```
argument: argument
argument: argument
argument: argument
```

I think I did something wrong in 'system' function in R code. **How can I invoke the OS command and send argument together?**

The reason I am testing this is because I want to obtain myVector in MyRcode.R, and submit slurm job and send the myVector elements as arguments. The slurm job will run another R code in supercomputer clusters (parallel running) with the received arguments.

Thank you,

Comment: You've quoted `"argument"` as part of the string, so it's not referring to the variable `argument`. `paste` the command together: `system(paste("./Shell_RunCalculations.sh", argument))`

Comment: Oh, thank you for your help! I tested and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

- `system2()` or
- `system()` in combination with `paste()`

to execute a shell command from R. In the following example, the shell command `echo` is called from R with a string argument.

```
arg <- "I am an R argument."
system2("echo", arg)
I am an R argument.
```

or

```
system(paste("echo", arg))
I am an R argument.
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, Florian.  I didn't know that I can use 'system2().'  Thank you!!

Comment: @Sanghoon I am glad the answer is useful for you. You could accept it. Then your question will no longer appear as unanswered question on stackoverflow...

Comment: Oh, I should accept the answer to make my question not appear as unanswered question. I accepted your answer. Thank you for letting me know.